# Add the sub dictonary element in list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to add my sub dictionary element in list. It is giving me type error.
Here is dictionary and my code:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": {
        "skey1": "svalue2",
        "skey2": {
            "sskey1": [{
                "url": "value",
                "sid": "511"
            },
                {
                    "url": "value",
                    "sid": "522"
                },
                {
                    "url": "value",
                    "sid": "533"
                }]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add the sid into the list like `[511,522,533]`:

here is my code:

```
rsId=[]
for i in op['key2']['skey2']['sskey1']:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if k=='sid':
            rsId.append(v)
```

Comment: There are commas missing.

Comment: that is not issue i just created dummy dictionary

Comment: you are getting type error ??? it's only syntax error caused by missing comma nothing else; code is giving desire output. if not then show full traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
D = { 
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":{ 
             "skey1":"svalue2",
             "skey2":{
                        "sskey1":[{ 
                                    "url":"value",
                                    "sid":"511"
                                  },
                                  { 
                                    "url":"value",
                                    "sid":"522"
                                  },
                                  { 
                                    "url":"value",
                                    "sid":"533"
                                  } ]
      }
  }   
}

res = []
for i in D['key2']['skey2']['sskey1']:
    res.append(i['sid'])
print res
```

Result:

```
['511', '522', '533']
```

or a one line code:

```
res = [i['sid'] for i in D['key2']['skey2']['sskey1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
rsId = [v for item in op['key2']['skey2']['sskey1'] for k, v in item.items() if k == 'sid']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with one line something like this:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x['sid'],data['key2']['skey2']['sskey1'])))
```

output:

```
['511', '522', '533']
```

If you want value in int then:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:int(x['sid']),data['key2']['skey2']['sskey1'])))
```

output:

```
[511, 522, 533]
```

when data is:

```
data = {
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":{
             "skey1":"svalue2",
             "skey2":{
                        "sskey1":[{
                                    "url":"value",
                                    "sid":"511"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "url":"value",
                                    "sid":"522"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "url":"value",
                                    "sid":"533"
                                  } ]
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Get the int as output

> The type error is probably due to the fact that you get a string as item of the list. Let’s see it transforming it to a number wit int() it solves your problem.
>   The only change to your code is in the last line of code.

```
op = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": {
        "skey1": "svalue2",
        "skey2": {
            "sskey1": [{
                "url": "value",
                "sid": "511"
            },
                {
                    "url": "value",
                    "sid": "522"
            },
                {
                    "url": "value",
                    "sid": "533"
            }]
        }
    }
}

rsId = []
for i in op['key2']['skey2']['sskey1']:
    for k, v in i.items():
        if k == 'sid':
            rsId.append(int(v)) # put the int here
```

output

```
>>> rsId
[511, 522, 533]
```

**Another approach: checking every key that has a dictionary as value**

```
op = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": {
        "skey1": "svalue2",
        "skey2": {
            "sskey1": [
                {
                    "url": "value",
                    "sid": "511"
                },

                {
                    "url": "value",
                    "sid": "522"
                },

                {
                    "url": "value",
                    "sid": "533"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
l = []
for k in op: # searching in the main dictonary
    if type(op[k]) is dict: # if the value contains a dict (sub1)
        for k2 in op[k]:    # for every key
            if type(op[k][k2]) is dict: # if the value is a dict (sub2)
                for k3 in op[k][k2]: # for each key of subdict 2
                    for i in op[k][k2][k3]: # for every item of the list
                        for k4 in i: # foreach key in the item (a dict)
                            if k4 == 'sid': # if the key is 'sid'
                                l.append(int((i[k4]))) # append the value

print(l)
```

output

```
[511, 522, 533]
```